# ag grid with angular material tooltip

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid

Require information to use the mat tooltip with ag grid as able to use normal tooltip via

```
 valueFormatter: this.tooltipFormatter
        , tooltip: function (params) {
          return (params.valueFormatted);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ag grid does not support advanced tooltips yet.
You will have to write a custom cell Renderer Component something like this -

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: 'child-cell',
    template: `<span matTooltip="material tooltip">{{params.value}}</span>`
})
export class ChildMessageRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    public params: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    refresh(): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
```

More details on how to register your custom cell Renderer with your component is here - 
[Custom Component Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-dynamic-components)

[Registering framework components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/#registering-framework-components)